# XMPPPY with Openfire

Tags: python, xmpp, openfire, xmpppy

I'm trying to simply connect XMPPPY to Openfire, send a message, then close.  The problem is that I keep getting

(Python 2.6)

> > > import xmpp
> > >
> > > pwd = "password"
> > >
> > > jid=xmpp.protocol.JID("testuser@localhost")
> > >
> > > cl=xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain()) #which translates to 'localhost'
> > >
> > > cl.connect()

```
DEBUG: socket       start Plugging <xmpp.transports.TCPsocket instance at 0x190ea1b8> into <xmpp.client.Client instance at 0x190e5320>

DEBUG: socket       start Successfully connected to remote host ('localhost', 5222)

DEBUG: dispatcher   start Plugging <xmpp.dispatcher.Dispatcher instance at 0x190ea2d8> into <xmpp.client.Client instance at 0x190e5320>
```

> > > cl.auth(jid.getNode(),pwd) #translates to 'testuser' / 'password'

```
DEBUG: sasl         error Failed SASL authentification: <not-authorized />

DEBUG: sasl         stop  Plugging <xmpp.auth.SASL instance at 0x190f0320> out of <xmpp.client.Client instance at 0x190e5320>.
```

I'm 100% sure that the username and password are correct as I've tried many times and can connect via Spark.

Is there a setting somewhere that I'm missing / has anyone has success with this?

Answer (score 0):

lookup your jid format

jid=xmpp.protocol.JID("testuser@localhost")

the xmpp server name should same as name after '@'

check the xmpp server name at http://localhost:9090/index.jsp